# Python Panda if statement on date subtraction (age)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get this within Python pandas formula. I want a new column called "age", if resolved is blank, then do today-created, otherwise resolved-created.

Excel:

```excel
=IF(AA2="",(Piv!$E$1-X2),AA2-X2)
```

Pandas attempt:

```
df["Today"] = "2020-06-09"
df["Today"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Today"])

def Age(row):        
    Resolved = row[19]
    if Resolved == "":
        return (df["Today"] - df["Created"])
    else:
        return (df["Resolved"] - df["Created"])

df["Age"] = df.apply(Age, axis="columns")
```

Comment: Could you share what your excel sheet and/or DataFrame look like?

Comment: Sure, Today, Resolved, Created are all datetime  Dtypes (as columns). Resolved is sometimes blank. When its blank, i would like it to do first part of if statement on each applicable row. when its complete, i would like it to do resolved-created.

Comment: I fixed your `df["Age"] = df.apply...` statement indentation, obviously it has to be outside the function `Age()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have something going on with the apply function. You're passing it each row of the DataFrame but returning a Series instead of a scalar. Also, using the empty string `""` may not be the best practice here. Consider using NaT, the null type for datetimes.

The good news is, I think you can achieve this without a custom function using **list comprehension** combined with a **conditional expression**!

```
df['Age'] = [df.Resolved[i] - df.Created[i] if df.Resolved[i] != '' 
             else df.Today[i] - df.Created[i]
             for i in range(0,df.shape[0])]
```

If you want to stick with the custom function and apply method, try changing your return statements to be scalers. The function will get a Series for each row, so you can reference individual values using column names and return a scalar for each row. For example:

```
def Age(row):
    Res = row.Resolved
    if pd.isnull(Res):
        return (row.Today - row.Created)
    else:
        return (row.Resolved - row.Created)
```

Edit: Removed comment about the last line being indented; moderator fixed the typo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, some issues i am running with. Option1: this creates the Age column for me but (issue1)it returns whole numbers (<m8[ns). i need up to 2 decimals. issue (2) for rows that have a 'blank' resolved, it does not calculate. . i tried both df.Resolved[i] != 'NAT' and df.Resolved[i] != '' Option 2: for this one, i cant get column to generate, i added df["Age"] = df.apply(Age, axis="columns") at bottom. no luck.

Comment: What are the dtypes of the Resolved and Created columns? Option 1 should return a timedelta if both items are datetimes. The dtypes of these columns could also explain why Option 2 is not working. Be sure Resolved and Created are datetimes. Look at using `pd.to_datetime()` again. You can also try `if np.isnat(df.Resolved[i])` assuming Resolved is in datetime format. For option 2, the `df.apply()` function needs to be called from outside the custom Age function. Notice how the moderator changed your original post to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, i got option 2 to work if its outside custom Age function, it also seems to have issue where it doesn't work if resolved is blank. it returns blank. df ["Age"] dtype: timedelta64[ns]
df["Resolved"] dtype: datetime64[ns]
df["Created"] dtype: datetime64[ns]##
df["Today"] dtype: datetime64[ns], (set to 2020-06-09 for all rows)

def Age(row):
    Resolved = row.Today
    if Resolved == "":
        return (row.Today - row.Created)
    else:
        return (row.Resolved - row.Created)
        -----------------
        df["Age"] = .dfapply(Age, axis="columns")

Comment: I think I found an error in my Option 2 code. Check my edit in my answer. For some reason, I was checking if the Today column was blank and not the Resolved column. Also, we still may need to check against something other than blank. Is there any way you could run `df.Resolved.value_counts()` and share the output? I want to see what those "blank" values are actually being stored as. Blank can mean many different things.

Comment: df["Resolved"]
Name: Resolved, Length: 2523, dtype: datetime64[ns]
df.["Resolved"].value_counts()
Name: Resolved, Length: 2274, dtype: int64
df["Resolved"].isnull().sum()
197, all of the blanks are NaT

Comment: issue is still there :(, here is picture https://ibb.co/MDn8HRP

Comment: Try the revision in my answer. Sorry this is taking so many efforts! I'm still learning myself! The new version checks for NaT rather than a blank string.

Comment: Awesome! Glad we finally got there!